# How to install Swift package via package manager?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-package-manager

I am currently following the document from [swift.org](https://swift.org/package-manager/#example-usage) to play around with the new Swift Package Manager.

I cloned the demo project from [Github](https://github.com/apple/example-package-dealer) and run the following command from terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/apple/example-package-dealer.git
cd example-package-dealer
swift build
.build/debug/Dealer
```

While I run `swift build`, error arise.

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: 'build'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I stuck for an hour. Sadly, it's just an epic fail that downloading the wrong swift package. If you want to use `swift build`, MAKE SURE you download the **development** version.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Hopefully people scroll down this far. Thank you!

Comment: To further corroborate this as the answer: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-build-dev/Week-of-Mon-20160321/000362.html

Comment: Sometimes its `xcrun --find swift` command you need also enter before `swift build`

Comment: so what to do ?

Answer (score 6):

You did not add the newly installed swift to your `PATH`. The instructions for doing that are [here](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift).

On OS X:

```
export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

On Linux:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Swift/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

Then to test it works:

```
swift build --version
```

Comment: I got the same issue too. `error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build (No such file or directory)`

Comment: You need to download the DEVELOPMENT snapshot and not the release one.

Comment: thanks~ I figured out eventually though it look me couple hours.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and in my case, I recently updated my Xcode to 8.2.1 and swift 3.0 comes with it.
I was getting this log.

```
Ranvijay-Mac-mini:PerfectTemplate ranaranvijaysingh$ swift build
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift-build (No such file or directory)
```

The path it was taking was incorrect. It was suppose to be:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

To change the path, run this command.

```
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH
```

And DONE.

Run : `swift build` again on your project and if you get this error.

```
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' from command line tools installation
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
error: Invalid platform path
```

then you need to change the SDK path as well.
In my case,  I had two .sdk at path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/ 

MacOSX.sdk  MacOSX10.12.sdk
```

To know what is your SDK path, run this command.

```
xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
```

My case i got this.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

To change it run this command.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and NOW DONE.
Try running `swift build` now.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a problem with the latest snapshot:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Swift 2.2 Snapshot of January 11 contains swift-build in usr/bin
- Ubuntu 14.04 Swift 2.2 Snapshot of January 25 doesn't contain swift-build in usr/bin

Besides, the January 25 release also seems to miss other files (libFoundation.so and libXCTest.so in usr/lib/swift/linux for instances).

Either there has been a structure change....or, simply, the latest snapshot had a problem ;)
While they fix the snapshot, simply take the older (January 11th) snapshot, and you should be fine.