# Why is Swift build command only available in development?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm learning Swift now, and I found out that the `swift build` command is available only in the development version of Swift.

So when I invoke

```
swift build
```

...it returns:

> swift build unable to invoke subcommand.

Can someone explain why?

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010843/5612645) I found the above command, but why is it only available in the development version?

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce your situation?

Comment: when I invoke `swift build` it retuns me `swift build unable to invoke subcommand`. Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35010843/5612645 I found the answer but I don't understand why it is available only in development version.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Package Manager is included with Swift 3.0 and above. You should be able to use it now with the released versions that are included with Xcode 8 or downloadable on [swift.org](https://swift.org/download/).